# How does FB select the top ten friends in a user profile?

Tags: facebook, algorithm

I'm wondering how does the Facebook Friends Column works on the Facebook Profile page (not the timeline). All this while, I've been observing that the Friends column displays the Profiles which one has visited the most such as the top 10 viewed profile from a User.

Does anyone know how this arrangement works? Whether it's just a random shuffle of profiles to be shown in that category or is there specific arrangement or pattern? Are there any articles, posts or interviews discussing this?

Answer (score 1):

Here's your answer: https://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=116320945119338

> Facebook does not select friends to show based on whose profiles you choose to view or who you interact with over messages and chat.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the page. I never searched for the answer on facebook itself.

Comment: But there is something that tells me not to believe what's said on the page :)

Comment: Well it's from the official Facebook FAQs so you won't find an answer more authoritative than this. Plus, I doubt they're going to make the algorithm behind this public so you cannot expect to know it from elsewhere.

Comment: I have been studying the trends for over a couple of months now, without any interaction with friends and just checking the friends list. What I notice is: Everyday, there's a change of 5 members from the list. And I can not relate this with the statement "This selection might include friends who you interact with the most in Wall posts, comments and mutually attended events" (from fb)

Comment: I'm not disagreeing with you :) From your observations, it is reasonable to make that conjecture but my point is that I think it is very unlikely for you to be able to confirm it.

Comment: that's true. I don't want FB to disclose the algo themselves. Just was wondering if we could reverse engineer through it :)

Answer (score 0):

Unlike what FB says publicly, I am almost 100% certain now that those friends that you chat with most come on top.  The 'interact publicly' does not make sense, because interact publicly means, one has to be able to see the conversation or comments by anyone (public), but without seeing any of so-called public interaction, weird names still come on top. The answer is simple, the names are arranged according to the frequency of your private messages or chat with the person

Answer (score -1):

facebook will NEVER tell the truth. Watch "Terms and conditions may apply"